# Cannot use Rayon's `.par_iter()`

Tags: parallel-processing, iterator, rust, rayon

I have a struct which implements `Iterator` and it works fine as an iterator. It produces values, and using `.map()`, I download each item from a local HTTP server and save the results. I now want to parallelize this operation, and [Rayon](https://github.com/nikomatsakis/rayon) looks friendly.

I am getting a compiler error when trying to follow the example in the documentation.

This is the code that works sequentially. `generate_values` returns the struct which implements `Iterator`. `dl` downloads the values and saves them (i.e. it has side effects). Since iterators are lazy in Rust, I have put a `.count()` at the end so that it will actually run it.

```
generate_values(14).map(|x| { dl(x, &path, &upstream_url); }).count();
```

Following the Rayon example I tried this:

```
generate_values(14).par_iter().map(|x| { dl(x, &path, &upstream_url); }).count();
```

and got the following error:

```
src/main.rs:69:27: 69:37 error: no method named `par_iter` found for type `MyIterator` in the current scope
```

Interestingly, when I use `.iter()`, which many Rust things use, I get a similar error:

```
src/main.rs:69:27: 69:33 error: no method named `iter` found for type `MyIterator` in the current scope
src/main.rs:69     generate_values(14).iter().map(|tile| { dl_tile(tile, &tc_path, &upstream_url); }).count();
```

Since I implement `Iterator`, I should get `.iter()` for free right? Is this why `.par_iter()` doesn't work?

Rust 1.6 and Rayon 0.3.1

```
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.6.0 (c30b771ad 2016-01-19)
```

Comment: We cannot help without the code :( Do you have a small (reduced) example exhibiting the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rayon 0.3.1 defines [`par_iter`](https://github.com/nikomatsakis/rayon/blob/v0.3.1/src/par_iter/mod.rs#L57-L62) as:

```
pub trait IntoParallelRefIterator<'data> {
    type Iter: ParallelIterator<Item=&'data Self::Item>;
    type Item: Sync + 'data;

    fn par_iter(&'data self) -> Self::Iter;
}
```

There is only [one type that implements this trait in Rayon itself: `[T]`](https://github.com/nikomatsakis/rayon/blob/v0.3.1/src/par_iter/slice.rs#L26-L33):

```
impl<'data, T: Sync + 'data> IntoParallelRefIterator<'data> for [T] {
    type Item = T;
    type Iter = SliceIter<'data, T>;

    fn par_iter(&'data self) -> Self::Iter {
        self.into_par_iter()
    }
}
```

That's why [Lukas Kalbertodt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35864306/155423) to `collect` to a `Vec` will work; `Vec` dereferences to a slice.

Generally, Rayon could not assume that *any* iterator would be amenable to parallelization, so it cannot default to including all `Iterator`s.

Since you have defined `generate_values`, you could implement the appropriate Rayon trait for it as well:

1. `IntoParallelIterator`
2. `IntoParallelRefIterator`
3. `IntoParallelRefMutIterator`

That should allow you to avoid collecting into a temporary vector.

Answer (score 6):

No, the `Iterator` trait has nothing to do with the `iter()` method. Yes, this is slightly confusing.

There are a few different concepts here. An `Iterator` is a type that can spit out values; it only needs to implement `next()` and has many other methods, but none of these is `iter()`. Then there is `IntoIterator` which says that a type can be transformed into an `Iterator`. This trait has the `into_iter()` method. Now the `iter()` method is not *really* related to any of those two traits. It's just a normal method of many types, that often works similar to `into_iter()`.

Now to your Rayon problem: it looks like you can't just take any normal iterator and turn it into a parallel one. However, I never used this library, so takes this with a grain of salt. To me it looks like you need to collect your iterator into a `Vec` to be able to use `par_iter()`.

And just as a note: when using normal iterators, you shouldn't use `map()` and `count()`, but rather use a standard `for` loop.

Comment: I used a for loop initially. I only wrote it as a `.map().count()` so that I could use `.par_iter()`.

Comment: I already assumed that :) Just wanted to state this for future readers, since one can easily become trapped in the "iterators are awesome - iterator adapters for everything" mindset, like I did ^_^