# How can I use Rayon to parallelize iteration over iter::from_fn?

Tags: rust, parallel-processing, iterator, rayon

I have a function that I'm using to generate an iterator using `iter::from_fn`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58683171/6335363).

```rs
fn generate_iterator<'a>(
    some_arg: Box<dyn SomeTrait>,
    some_other_arg: &'a [InputType],
) -> impl Iterator<Item = OutputType> + 'a {
    // ...
    iter::from_fn(move || {
        // ...
        Some(value)
    })
}
```

As this iterator can produce millions (if not billions) of items, I am hoping to speed up iteration by using [Rayon](https://crates.io/crates/rayon) to parallelize the iteration.

```rs
// This is far too slow
generate_iterator(&some_arg)
    .filter(|item| some_logic(item))
    .collect()
```

However, when I add Rayon into the code, I receive a confusing error

```rs
let matches = generate_iterator(&some_arg)
    .par_iter()
    .filter(|item| some_logic(item))
    .collect_vec();
```

```
error[E0599]: the method `par_iter` exists for opaque type `impl Iterator<Item = OutputType>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> path/to/my/code.rs:92:10
   |
91 |       let matches = generate_iterator(&some_arg)
   |  ___________________-
92 | |         .par_iter()
   | |         -^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `impl Iterator<Item = OutputType>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   | |_________|
   | 
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `&impl Iterator<Item = OutputType> + '_: IntoParallelIterator`
           which is required by `impl Iterator<Item = OutputType> + '_: rayon::iter::IntoParallelRefIterator<'_>`
```

It appears that I need to implement `IntoParallelIterator`, which is also suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35869613/6335363). However, as I didn't directly create the type for the iterator that Rayon is attempting to parallelize, I am unsure how I can implement this trait. I think I might need to add a `where` clause to my return type annotation for `generate_iterator`, but I'm not sure where to start with this.

As the iterator contains an inordinate number of elements, I cannot collect it into a `Vec` as an intermediary step.

How can I adjust my code such that I can use Rayon to easily parallelize the iteration over `iter::from_fn`?

Here are some permalinks to the actual code if there is any context missing:

- [generator function](https://github.com/MiguelGuthridge/Enigma-Breaker/blob/f1a94762b144d9c24871a3344099d57d83a3d9df/lib_enigma/src/brute_force/combinations.rs#L7)
- [parallel iteration](https://github.com/MiguelGuthridge/Enigma-Breaker/blob/miguel-use-rayon/lib_enigma/src/brute_force/force.rs#L91)

Comment: I seriously doubt that'll do you any good – your function has to run and produce the items in series anyways – but [`par_bridge`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelBridge.html#tymethod.par_bridge) is probably the method you're looking for.

Comment: @cafce25 it's a good start, but unfortunately it ends up requiring `impl Iterator<Item = OutputType>` to implement `Send`. I tried implementing `Send` on `OutputType` to see if that helped, but it didn't appear to make a difference.

Comment: To clarify, my iterator does produce items in series - that part is relatively fine - it's generating a bunch of potential states which then need to be validated. It's just the validation part that I want to parallelize, so I'm ok with the items being generated in series.

Comment: How do you want to work in different threads (required for in parallel) when your items are not `Send`? That can only work if you initially produce the items on different threads, which is not what `from_fn` can do.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I have tried making my item type `Send`, but it didn't appear to make a difference. The way I imagine Rayon would approach it would be to generate the values on one thread, then send them to worker threads to do the processing, collecting the filter results on the main thread. At the very least, if Rayon doesn't work out for me, that's what I'll end up doing myself.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the documentation seems to suggest that `par_bridge` specifically exists to convert a sequential iterator to a parallel one: """This creates a “bridge” from a sequential iterator to a parallel one, by distributing its items across the Rayon thread pool. This has the advantage of being able to parallelize just about anything"""

Comment: Yes, it **distributes** aka `Send`s the items across the threadpool.

Comment: Therefore implementing `Send` on the item type should work, right?

Comment: Yes, I think I misunderstood your [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77446876/how-can-i-use-rayon-to-parallelize-iteration-over-iterfrom-fn#comment136534482_77446876) slightly. Maybe the problem is that both the item *and* the iterator itself have to be `Send`⁉

Comment: Unfortunately, implementing `Send` doesn't appear to work. `method cannot be called on "impl Iterator<Item = MachineState>" due to unsatisfied trait bounds. note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied: "impl Iterator<Item = MachineState> + '_: Send" ...`

Comment: Yes, the *iterator* has to implement `Send` as well which in turn means the closure you pass to `from_fn` has to implement `Send` which it does given it abides by the [rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/closure.html#other-traits) apparently your current function does not.

Comment: @cafce25 thanks so much! I've gotten it working now! Turns out the values captured by the closure weren't all `Send`. After modifying the parameters to specify this, it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

This happened because one of the arguments to the generator function didn't implement `Send`. The `Iterator` generated by `iter::from_fn` [automatically implements `Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/closure.html#other-traits) if the `Item` type implements `Send`, and if all data captured by the closure it receives [implements `Send` as well](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/special-types-and-traits.html#auto-traits).

Unfortunately, one of my arguments was a `Box<dyn SomeTrait>`, meaning that the implementation of `Send` was not explicit.

I was able to fix this by specifying that the argument to my generator function needed to implement `Send`.

```rs
let my_arg: Box<dyn SomeTrait + Send> = ...
```